# Laravel4.2 ORM Eloquent Update Method

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to know the problem related to this code, first I use a table without primary key when I run the following code to an update, I did not have any answer:

```
Upload::where('nameimgs', '=', $imgsended)
        ->update(array('nameimgs' => $ imgname));
```

but the problem is solved when I replace the code by :

```
DB::table('uploads')
     ->where('nameimgs', '=', $ imgsended)
     ->update(array('nameimgs' => $ imgname));
```

nevertheless with the deleting method, i did not have any problem, to share knowledge with laravalists I want to know if the problem is related to version Laravel4.2 or Laravel ORM eloquent for the update method require the primary key "id" as like as the save method.

Comment: can you `dd(Upload::where('nameimgs', '=', $imgsended)->get()->toArray())` and `dd(DB::table('uploads')::where('nameimgs', '=', $imgsended)->get()->toArray())` and post the output for both?

Answer (score 0):

Is the exact code you have in your project? If so, you have spaces in the field names, and you are missing a comma in the first where.

```
Upload :: where ('nameimgs '' = ', $ imgsended) -> update (array (' nameimgs' => $ imgname));
DB :: table ('uploads') -> where ('nameimgs', '=', $ imgsended) -> update (array ('nameimgs' => $ imgname) );
```

It should look like this:

```
Upload::where('nameimgs', $imgsended)
    ->update([
        'nameimgs' => $imgname
    ]);
DB::table('uploads')
    ->where('nameimgs', $imgsended)
    ->update([
        'nameimgs' => $imgname
    ]);
```

Try my code see if that fixes anything. If that doesnt work, can we see you Upload model?

Comment: I don't have any spaces an the field names, i use the code like this Upload::where('nameimgs', '=', $imgsended)->update(array('nameimgs' => $imgname)); but it's not working.